# On google.co.uk, why is my site ranked higher in Firefox than in other desktop browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, seo

For https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mobile+website+design , this is where my site - http://mobilewebexpert.co.uk/ - is listed:

IE: 4th.
Chrome: 4th.
Opera: 4th.
Safari: 4th.
Firefox: 1st.
Firefox (using a Chrome User-agent): 1st.
Firefox (using a Chrome User-agent and all cookies deleted): 1st.

...they all agree except Firefox. And, as you can see, it doesn't appear to be Google deciding that my site should rank higher for Firefox because on the last two tests Firefox reported itself as being Chrome.

Does anyone know why Firefox results would be so different?

Comment: FYI, for me it's #6 (Firefox). Are you sure that you deleted all cookies? Google even creates a "search profile" for users not logged-in.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably logged in to your Google account, which personalizes your results.

Browsers have no impact whatsoever on actual SERPs.

Comment: I wasn't logged in to my Google account... Would you mind trying the google link in Firefox on your machine and telling me where my site appears?

Comment: Tested from another machine at it's ranked #4 in Firefox. Can only think the difference must be due to one of the Firefox developer plugins I have installed.